# Rav Ruderman interview at Chofetz Chaim

Tags: english, talmidei-chakhamim

I just heard that a friend of mine once heard an interview of Rav Ruderman zt"l (of Ner Yisroel), by Chofetz Chaim talmidim - in English. I didn't even know that he spoke English.
Does anyone have a link for access to that interview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [here](http://uberdox.aishdas.org/2010/04/first-hand-details-about-the-alter-of-slabodka) a website which mentions an interview in English that he had with Chofetz Chaim talmidim about the Alter of Slabodka - is that what your friend could have meant? It writes there:

> I almost had to make sure I wasn’t dreaming, when I download and started listening to the recording of an interview with former Slabodka talmid, and founder of Yeshiva Ner Israel, Rav Yaakov Yitzchok Ruderman zt’l.
>
> The recording of R Ruderman is available **[here](https://torahdownloads.com/shiur-24397.html)**.  The mp3 is a series of questions and answers about the Alter of Slabodka, Rav Nosson Tzvi Finkel conducted by students from Yeshiva Chofetz Chaim, prior to 1987 (when R Ruderman was niftar).

Comment: It's often really hard to understand him; is he dropping into Yiddish a lot?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to listen to it yet sorry